# Using Gstreamer Python module with IronPython

Tags: python, .net, ironpython, pygobject, python.net

I want to use GStreamer Python Binding in my ASP.NET application as a plugin of Gstreamer I need is available in GStreamer's Python binding rather than its C# binding.
To achieve the goal I have done the following steps:

1. Install PTVS 2.2 from [here](https://microsoft.github.io/PTVS/)
2. Install IronPython 2.7.6.3 from [here](http://ironpython.net/download/)
3. Install Python 2.7.12 from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
4. Install [Pygi 3.18.2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/) on the installation folder of Python 2.7
5. Create a Python file shown as follows:

   ```
   def Streaming():
    import gi; 
    gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0'); 
    from gi.repository import Gst; 
    Gst.init(None); 
    pipeline = Gst.parse_launch('playbin uri=http://docs.gstreamer.com/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm'); 
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING); 
    bus = pipeline.get_bus();
    msg = bus.timed_pop_filtered(Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE, Gst.MessageType.ERROR | Gst.MessageType.EOS)
   ```

   Then I tested it in a single Python application I created for testing with Python 2.7 interpreter and launcher, it just worked fine.
6. Create an ASP.NET application and write the following code to invoke the scripts:

   ```
     var python = Python.CreateRuntime();
     dynamic script =    python.UseFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Streaming.py");
     script.Streaming();
   ```

   When I run it, I got an error that `ImportError: No module named 'gi'`.
   After online search for this problem, I found that I need to add the lib   directory of the Gstreamer Python module to IronPython's path, so I put the following code on the beginning of my Python script.

   ```
    import sys;
    sys.path.append('C:\\Python27\\Lib');
    sys.path.append('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages');
   ```

   But when I run it, I got another error: `cannot import _gi from gi`. I searched it online, while this time I couldn't find any useful information for that. To figure it out, I put the script in the testing Python application I created before, building and running it with IronPython interpreter and launcher. Then the application throwed an exception on the file `init__.py`, which is shown on the following screenshot image:

[image]
How can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you mixing IronPython and CPython?

Comment: PyGObject is using CPython C-API, so it is not likely to work on IronPython. But you can embed CPython in .NET using pythonnet.